# Trying to Delete Lines if there is a specific word Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have exported a Report which provides a Daily Backup Status Report. Each Server has a Parent Job as well as Child Jobs, I don't care about the Child Jobs as the Parent Job provides the actual success/failure of the server The child jobs have the word Default* and if that word is located on that line I would like to delete the entire line. I reviewed some of the additional help but wasn't able to successfully get the lines to truncate. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: try typing `:1,$ !grep -v Default*` oops! that would only work in `vim`.  maybe you should try using vim :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you have something like this:

```
Parent 1
Child11 Default
Child12 Default
Parent 2
Child21 Default
Child22 Default more
```

And you want it to result in this:

```
Parent 1
Parent 2
```

If so, the following will work in Notepad++:

```
Find:  ^.*Default.*\r\n
Replace:
```

From Notepad++ 6.5.1:

[image]

Explanation:

```
^.*Default.*\r\n

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or 
  after a line break character) «^»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
   giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the characters “Default” literally «Default»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
   giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match a carriage return character «\r»
Match a line feed character «\n»

Created with RegexBuddy
```

Note: I am not affiliated with RegexBuddy in any way; I've just used it for quite some time to design and test regular expressions in various dialects.

Comment: Thanks so much I ran the report and it worked as I asked. I now realize it would be better to display just the Parent Job so I should have asked to only display a line with a certain keyword such as "Weekly" all other lines should be removed. So like your example above only display lines with the word Parent but in my specific instance it would be Weekly. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have a requirement different than what you've asked here, please post it as a new question. I've answered the one you asked here, which was how to delete the lines containing `Default`. It's pretty unfair to change your requirements after asking the question and receiving a correct answer (that you've tested and confirm is correct). "I've checked your answer, and it works for what I wanted then, but I decided to change my mind about what I want, so answer a different question instead" isn't very polite. :-)